# How to compare 2 different List<LatLng>?

Tags: java, google-maps, arraylist, coordinates

I'm having traffic signals latitude and longitude in one List ArrayList. next, I have all latitude and longitude from the source to destination in second ListArrayList. how to compare one and second list and take only matching latitude and longitude

no, I'm stuck on it. I don't know how to solve this.

```
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import java.util.List;
    public class Paters {
        public List<LatLng> points;
    }


    List<Paters> pather = new ArrayList<Paters>();
    pathss.points = 
    decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));
    pather.add(pathss);
    listener.onLocationsgetted(pather);
![pather holding these values][1]
https://imgur.com/70RZjht

     public  void onLocationsgetted(List<Paters> pather) {
         List<LatLng> list2 = new ArrayList<LatLng>();`
//these are the traffic signal latitude and longitude
        `list2.add(new LatLng(13.23907, 80.04534));
         list2.add(new LatLng(13.05674, 80.23662));
         list2.add(new LatLng(13.04353, 80.23627));
         list2.add(new LatLng(13.01215, 80.23654));
         list2.add(new LatLng(13.01715, 80.24235));
         list2.add(new LatLng(13.03366, 80.97431));
     }
```

I expect to get all the matching latitude and longitudes only.

Comment: you are searching for the intersection of those groups. Look at `Collection.retainAll` to filter a collection based on another collection

Comment: it's returning true or false only in android studio

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but see if it works:

```
for(LatLng latlng: list1) {
    if(list2.contains((LatLng) latlng) {
        list3.add(latlng);
    }
}
```

If you are ok using Commons Collections, by all means use this:

```
CollectionUtils.intersection(list2, list1);
```

BTW it returns a Collection!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Paters p : pather) { p.points.retainAll(list2); }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: The code is self-explanatory, it's just 1 line with a for loop and a retainAll call. Why do I need to provide some extra text to explain the obvious? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Paters> al = new ArrayList<>();    
pathss.points =decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));
al.add(pathss);

public  void onLocationsgetted(Paters pathss){
List<LatLng> list2 = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
List<LatLng> list3 = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
list2.add(new LatLng(13.23907, 80.04534));
list2.add(new LatLng(13.05674, 80.23662));
list2.add(new LatLng(13.04353, 80.23627));
list2.add(new LatLng(13.01215, 80.23654));
list2.add(new LatLng(13.01715, 80.24235));`

for(LatLng p : pathss.points){
    if(list2.contains(p)){
    list3.add(p);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions friends, I tried this... Thanks a lot friends